# OpenOffice - понять как составить формулу

Tags: open-office

Есть два столбца с ячейками.

**A1:A100** - цифры от **1** до **100**

**B1:B100** - текстовые данные

Нужно получить в список данные ячеек **B1:B100** где **A1:A100 >=20** и **A1:A100<=50**

Не могу понять какой функцией(ями) это можно сделать, а именно задать два условия одному range ячеек

Comment: Используя функцию листа И(), объединить два условия в одно...

Comment: В этом примере все работает IF(AND(A6>=20;A6<=50);A6), здесь сразу указанная ячейка с подходящим условием, НО, как только я указываю не ячейки а их диапазоны, то выдает всегда 0  :  IF(AND(A1:A100>=20;A1:A100<=50);B1:B100)

Comment: Ну такую штуку следует вводить как формулу массива... А Вы как ввели? Да и вообще не очень понятно, что требуется... в частности, неясно, какого вывода и куда именно Вы ожидаете.

Comment: Как это не понятно, все довольно просто, дело в том что не просто понять как сделать два условия для одного диапазона.
К примеру чтобы было понятнее приведу пример с одним условием и формулой которая работает, нажимаю на ячеяку далее data>validity>range cell
вставляю формулу IF(A1:A100>20; B1:B100), после чего в ячейке появляются результаты текстов у который соседняя ячейка меньше 20.

Comment: Странно что никто не может решить задачу где нужно всего-то два условия, если быть еще понятней то поиск числе идет типа как в функции between

Comment: звучать это будет примерно так: select all data from B1:B100 where A1:A100 >=20 AND A1:A100<=50 и вывести это в List